# Jenkins Ant Build failed for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, jenkins, ant

I am using Jenkins on MAC for CI, I have fetched the android project from SVN and under "**Build**" I used "**Invoke ant**" and below are my parameters

**Ant version - Ant**

**Target -debug**

**Build file -path of my project/build.xml**

**Properties -sdk.dir=/Users/Mac002/Android**

**However when I try to build the project I am getting below error:**

Buildfile: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Project/workspace/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.4.1

[checkenv] Installed at /Users/Mac002/Android

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Project
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 23.0.2

```
 [echo] Resolving Build Target for Project...
```

[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2

[gettarget] API level:        19

```
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Resolving Dependencies for Project...
```

BUILD FAILED
**/Users/Mac002/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:573: ../../../../android-support-v7-appcompat resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Project/workspace**

Total time: 3 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure